# How do I create x number of textboxes in my view to enter data into a list or dictionary that is part of the model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, dictionary, model

Sorry for the awkward question, I wasn't sure how to phrase it.  What I have is a question model where I have several strings, and one dictionary (which I will use to store the answers, and the number of votes each answer gets.  I'm a PHP guy, and very new to ASP so I'm not totally sure if I am doing this correctly - so feel free to constructively criticize the way I'm doing it :)

When someone creates a question, they can have a set number of answers they want others to chose from - say 5 for example.  So I want the createQuestion view to display 5 textboxes for the answers to be entered, and each of those textboxes should relate to the first 5 key items in the dictionary.  I can then set the values of each to 0 when saving the question.  They will be saved as an XML file and only the number of answers given will be actually saved (so if I allow for 5, and they only use 3 then only 3 will actually appear in the saved XML format).

So in the model I have something like this (simplified):

```
public class QuestionModel {

        public int sampleId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Question")]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, int> Answers { get; set; }
```

I'm also initializing the Dict in a constructor:

```
   public QuestionModel() {
        this.Answers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }
```

And this is where I come unstuck.  I simply have no idea how to iterate a number of times through making textboxes in the view to add information to the Dict...  I'm using the following to add the question:

```
Question:<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Question) %>
```

but I can't seem to get anything to work in terms of making a list of textboxes for the answers.  I need something like this, although I realise I probably need to add the answers rather than assign them this way.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
    Answer <%= i%><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Answers[i])%>
<% } %>
```

I'd really appreciate some guidance or nudges in the right direction.  I've had to resort to having 5 separate strings (Answer1, Answer2, etc) at the moment, and 5 corresponding ints... but this seems hideous... there must be a way...

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `Dictionary<string,int>`, create a new class (lets call it Answer) with properties to represent both the string and the int.  Your Question class should then have a `List<Answer>` which you can easily loop over and render in your view.

You'll probably also want to add a `int ID` property to Answer and make your "vote" buttons include that in its route so that you can figure out server-side which answer was selected.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I've just implemented that as per your recommendation and I'm working on the view now - but I'm still not sure how to implement the correct number of text boxes and assign each one in the view?

Comment: For the createQuestion action, you are instatiating a Question object and passing that in as the model.  Add an extra line of code that initializes the Answers property of that object to `new List<Answer>(5)` which will put 5 empty answer objects in the model

Comment: Thanks Robert... I'm working on that now... I'll report back with how I get on, but it looks promising.